# Changing underline color of LanguageTool in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors, spelling, grammar

I've recently installed LanguageTool to check grammar and spelling mistakes in TeXstudio. However, I often miss the errors because the gray-bluish underlining makes them hard to spot. Is there a way to change the underlining to a distinctive color, such as red for example?

I checked [this forum](https://forum.languagetool.org/t/displaying-errors-in-colour/1031). It says I have to do some changes to the `.languagetool.cfg` file, but for some reason this file doesn't appear in File Explorer.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly: for some reason, instead of using TeXstudio's default dictionary (perhaps without support in your language) you have opted to use the standalone version of LanguageTool and you have a problem setting up the correct colors in your configuration file, so it doesn't display correctly in TeXstudio.

Comment: Apparently, your problem is in LanguageTool and not in TeXstudio or anything related to TeX and friends, so if my interpretation was correct, go back to that forum and look for the solution there. This question is outside of the topics we are discussing and should be resolved in the other forum, which is the most appropriate, otherwise please correct my mistake.

Comment: Did you try to change the colour in `texstudio preferences -> syntax highlighting -> spell checking`?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks very much that was exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the colour in `texstudio preferences -> syntax highlighting -> spell checking`

[image]