# underline color of LanguageTool in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I am asking the same question as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408420/changing-underline-color-of-languagetool-in-texstudio) since I have the same problem but the solution does not work for me. I am using language tool to verify the grammar, but it is almost impossible to see the underlined grammar mistake(it is gray). On the other hand, it overwrites the spelling of texstudio; hence, it is impossible to find spelling mistakes as well. Here are my questions:

1. How to fix the color problem? (texstudio preferences -> syntax highlighting does not work for me.)
2. Is it possible to force texstudio to use its own dictionary?

I am running Texstudio 12.6 on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
Somehow, language tool considers the spelling mistake as a grammar mistake, hence you need to change the color of grammerMistake in Language checking section of the Syntax Highlighting.